# MacOS: How to launch gui QProcess and bring it to front?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa

I'm trying to run gui application with QProcess, but it is not active by default:

```
qint64 pid = 0;
QProcess::startDetached(executable, args, wd, &pid); //The app is in background
```

---

I tried `activateWithOptions` and it doesn't help:

```
qint64 pid = 0;
QProcess::startDetached(executable, args, wd, &pid);

NSRunningApplication *app = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:static_cast<pid_t>(pid)];
[app activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps]; //The app is still in background
```

---

But if I add a small delay `activateWithOptions` works as expected:

```
qint64 pid = 0;
QProcess::startDetached(executable, args, wd, &pid);

QThread::msleep(2000);
NSRunningApplication *app = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:static_cast<pid_t>(pid)];
[app activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps]; //The app is in foreground!
```

But `QThread::msleep(2000)` looks like a dirty hack, and is not going to pass code review :)

So, my question is: How to start gui process and bring it to front without hacks?

**PS:** I know that `QProcess::startDetached("open", "-a " + executable);` might work, but it doesn't let specify working directory, so it doesn't suit me

**UPD:** Seems like I need to wait until the application [finished launching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication/1532002-finishedlaunching?language=objc), and then I'll be able to activate it.

Comment: What happens if you use `open -a script.sh` where `script.sh` is a bash script that then launches your desired executable?  Would that work?  Otherwise you might want to look at [`QTimer::singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-4) rather than `QThread::msleep(2000)`.

Comment: @G.M., as far as I understand, `open` always uses executable path as working directory. So launching it from script doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
    NSRunningApplication *waitForAppHandle(pid_t pid) const
    {
        forever {
            NSRunningApplication *app  = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: pid];
            if (app) 
                return app;
            }

            QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
        }
    }

    bool waitForLaunched(NSRunningApplication *app) const
    {

        forever {
            if ([app isFinishedLaunching]) {
                return;
            }

            QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
        }
    }

    void activate(pid_t pid)
    {
        NSRunningApplication *app = waitForAppHandle();
        waitForLaunched(app);

        [app activateWithOptions : NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
    }

    //...
    
    QProcess p;
    //...
    activate(p.processId());
```